# Return a string on C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, return

I'm getting a core dump that I have no clue how to solve. I have searched other questions and googled my problem but I just can't figure out how to solve this...

Here is the code:

```
const char checkExtension(const char *filename)
{
    const char *point = filename; 
    const char *newName = malloc(sizeof(filename-5));

    if((point = strrchr(filename,'.palz')) != NULL ) 
    {   
        if(strstr(point,".palz") == 0) 
        {
          strncpy(newName, filename, strlen(filename)-5); 
          printf("%s\n",newName );     // the name shows correctly
          return newName;              // Segmentation fault (core dumped)
        }
    }
    return point;
}
```

The function was called `char checkExtensions(const char *filename)`. I added the const due the solutions that I have found online but so far I haven't been able to make it work...
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Strings are represented by "char *" or "const char *" in C. Your function, as written, returns a "const char" (note the lack of a pointer).

Comment: @JoshPetrie so I cant return a char? I have to return it from reference?

Comment: Returning a `char` is just a single character.

Comment: @thelaws so my only solution is to return it from reference, right?

Comment: Yes you must return a `char *`. 
But be careful, your function has memory management issues. The caller has no idea if they need to free the return value or not

Comment: `sizeof(filename-5)` is the size of a pointer. That's not what you mean.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I wanted a malloc to save a string withour an extension of a file, thats why there is a -5.

Comment: `filename-5` is a pointer, and so `sizeof(filename-5)` is the size of a pointer. That use of `sizeof` is evaluated by the **compiler**. It is absolutely not what you want. You allocated either 4 or 8 bytes depending on your pointer size. You did not mean to do that. Look at your call to `strncpy`.

Comment: What you really need to work out is what the function is meant to do. What is its specification?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the function recives a filename and it should return a new string, depending if the extesion is .palz or not, if it's .palz, it should return the name of the file without the extesion, otherwise if it have any other extension it should return the filename as it cames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many problems with your code. Here are some of them:

1. Your function returns `char` which is a single character. You need to return a pointer to an array of characters, a C string.
2. You don't allocate the right amount of memory. You use `sizeof()` on a pointer which yields the size of a pointer.
3. You make it impossible for the caller to know whether or not to deallocate memory. Sometimes you heap allocate, sometimes not. Your approach will leak.
4. You pass `'.palz'`, which is a character literal, to `strrchr` which expects a single `char`. What you mean to pass is `'.'`.

A better approach is to let the caller allocate the memory. Here is a complete program that shows how:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void GetNewFileName(const char *fileName, char *newFileName)
{
    const char *dot = strrchr(fileName, '.');
    if (dot)
    {
        if (strcmp(dot, ".palz") == 0)
        {
            size_t len = dot - fileName;
            memcpy(newFileName, fileName, len);
            newFileName[len] = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
    size_t len = strlen(fileName);
    memcpy(newFileName, fileName, len);
    newFileName[len] = 0;
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    char fileName[256];
    char newFileName[256];

    strcpy(fileName, "foo.bar");
    GetNewFileName(fileName, newFileName);
    printf("%s %s\n", fileName, newFileName);

    strcpy(fileName, "foo.bar.palz");
    GetNewFileName(fileName, newFileName);
    printf("%s %s\n", fileName, newFileName);

    strcpy(fileName, "foo.bar.palz.txt");
    GetNewFileName(fileName, newFileName);
    printf("%s %s\n", fileName, newFileName);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
foo.bar foo.bar
foo.bar.palz foo.bar
foo.bar.palz.txt foo.bar.palz.txt
```

Note that `strcmp` compares sensitive to letter case. On Windows file names are insensitive to case. I will leave that issue for you to deal with.

By letting the caller allocate memory you allow them to chose where the memory is allocated. They can use a local stack allocated buffer if they like. And it's easy for the caller to allocate the memory because the new file name is never longer than the original file name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you just explain me what does "size_t len = dot - fileName;"?
Why it is dot-fileName and not fileName - dot? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Because dot is greater than filename, it's the address of the final period in the string.

Comment: It is greater because the filename points to the address of the first letter of the file name and the dot points to the address of the ".", so it makes the dot greater, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably your problem:

`const char *newName = malloc(sizeof(filename-5));`

First, filename is of type `const char *`, which means that `(filename - 5)` is also of this type. Thus, `sizeof(filename - 5)` will always return the size of the pointer datatype of your architecture (4 for x32, 8 for x64).
So, depending on your architecture, you are calling either `malloc(4)` or `malloc(8)`.

The rest of the code doesn't even compile and it has serious string manipulation issues, so it's hard to tell what you were aiming at. I suppose the `strncpy()` was copying too much data into `newName` buffer, which caused buffer overflow.

If your goal was to extract the filename from a path, then you should probably just use `char *basename(char *path)` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Several pretty major problems with your code. Making it up as I type, so it may not fix *everything* first time right away. Bear with me.

1. You need to return a `char *`, not a `char`.

   ```
   const char checkExtension(const char *filename)
   {
       const char *point = filename;
   ```
2. You `malloc` memory but the instruction flow does not guarantee it will be freed or returned.
3. `sizeof(filename)` should be `strlen(filename)`, minus 5 (*sans* extension) but +1 (with terminating 0).

   ```
       const char *newName = malloc(sizeof(filename-5));
   ```
4. `strrchr` searches for a single character. Some compilers allow "multibyte character constants", but they expect something like 2 -- not *five*. Since you know the length and start of the string, use `strcmp`. (First ensure there *are* at least 5 characters. If not, no use in testing anyway.)

   ```
       if((point = strrchr(filename,'.palz')) != NULL ) {
   ```
5. Uh, `strstr` searches for a string inside a string and returns 0 if not found (actually `NULL`). This contradicts your earlier test. Remove it.

   ```
       if(strstr(point,".palz") == 0)
       {
   ```
6. `strncpy` copies `n` characters, but famously (and *documented*) does not add the terminating 0 if it did not get copied. You will have to this yourself.
7. .. This is actually where the `malloc` line should appear, right before *using* and *returning* it.

   ```
             strncpy(newName, filename, strlen(filename)-5);
             printf("%s\n",newName ); // the name shows correctly
             return newName; // Segmentation fault (core dumped)
         }
       }
   ```
8. You return the original string here. How do you know you need to `free` it, then? If you overwrote a *previous* `char *` its memory will be lost. Better to return a duplicate of the original string (so it can always be freed), or, as I'd prefer, return `NULL` to indicate "no further action needed" to the calling routine.

   ```
       return point;    
   }
   ```

Hope I did not forget anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- Wrong return type:

  > ```
  > const char checkExtension(const char *filename){
  > ```

  You need to return a pointer (`const char *`), not a single character.
- Not enough memory:

  > ```
  > const char checkExtension(const char *filename){
  >
  >   const char *newName = malloc(sizeof(filename-5));
  > ```

  You are allocating the **size of a pointer** (`char *`), which is typically 4 or 8. You need to call `strlen()` to find out the **size of the string**:
- Multibyte character:

  > ```
  > if((point = strrchr(filename,'.palz')) != NULL ) {
  > ```

  `'.palz'` is a multibyte character literal. While this is allowed in C, its value is implementation-defined and might not do what you expect. String literals use *double* quotes (`".palz"`).
- No terminating zero:

  > ```
  > strncpy(newName, filename, strlen(filename)-5);
  > ```

  Note that `strncpy()` doesn't necessarily null-terminate the target string. It write **at most** `strlen(filename)-5` characters. If the source string contains more characters (as in your case), it will **not** write a terminating zero.

---

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *checkExtension(const char *filename)
{
  int len = strlen (filename)-5;
  char *newName = NULL; /* return NULL on allocation failure. */

  if (len > 0 && !strcmp (filename+len, ".palz")) {
    newName = malloc (len+1);
    if (newName) {
      memcpy (newName, filename, len);
      newName[len] = 0;
    }
  }

  return newName;
}

int main (int ac, char **av)
{
  if (ac > 1) {
    const char *p = checkExtension (av[1]);
    puts (p ? p : "NULL");
  } else {
    puts ("?");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple errors here. You have not said what you are trying to achieve, that has to be implied from the code. You have declared `point` and `newName` as `const`, yet reassigned with a value. You have tested `strstr() == 0` when it should be `strstr() == NULL`. You have called `strrchr(filename,'.palz')` but sent a string instead of a char. Then you have returned the local variable `point` which goes out of scope before you get a chance to use it, because it was not declared as static. So it's irrelevant whether you returned a char or a char pointer.

```
char *checkExtension(const char *filename) {
    // if filename has extension .palz return a pointer to
    // the filename stripped of extension or return NULL
    char *point;
    static char newName[512];
    strncpy(newName, filename, 512);
    if ((point = strstr(newName, ".palz")) != NULL ) {
        if (strlen (point) == 5) {
            *point = 0; // string terminator
            // printf("%s\n",newName ); // use only for debugging
            return newName;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Alternatively provide a string the function can modify -

```
char *checkExtension(const char *filename, char *newName) { ... }
```

Alternatively provide a filename the function can modify -

```
char *checkExtension(char *filename) {
    char *point;
    if ((point = strstr(filename, ".palz")) != NULL ) {
        if (strlen (point) == 5) {
            *point = 0; // string terminator
            return filename;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```